# Which import directive will import a symbol from a DLL and not add a prefix? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

The short question is: **Which directive adds no prefix to an imported symbol?**

I have a library that is 100% C **(no C++ and not C compiled with a C++ compiler)** It's C top to bottom. (I have to mention that because sometimes folks confuse how Visual Studio works when compiling C using the C++ compiler with C using a C compiler.)

The library was compiled with CMAKE and it outputted a DLL with a symbol table that looks like this:

```
dumpbin.exe /exports mydll.dll

...stuff...    
1    0 00001087 mylib_get_x
..etc..
```

There's a static lib file too.

```
dumpbin.exe /exports mydll.lib

...stuff...
mylib_get_x
```

Notice how there are no weird prefixes?  (i.e. no *imp* on the symbols)  This makes the DLL extremely useful when trying to import the functions into things like the FFI in LuaJIT and other compilers/environments.

And I have an app that uses "mylib_get_x()"

```
/* myfile.c */

... stuff ...

int x;
x = mylib_get_x();
```

The result is: `unresolved external symbol _mylib_get_x referenced in function ...`

If I prefix the mylib_get_x() with any of these:

```
__declspec(dllimport)
__cdecl
__stdcall
_cdecl
extern
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
<nothing>
```

It doesn't matter.  It won't work.  They add prefixes.  Which one adds *nothing*?

When it was compiled, it had __declspec(dllexport) on it, but it's a 3rd party library, so somehow they got it to avoid the extra prefixes.

I can link in the supplied .lib file that was generated. Same result.  (see the dumpbin above that shows the symbol table from the .lib file without prefixes) I can create a manual .def file, generate a lib file from it and link to that. Same result.

I would love it if someone could explain what prefixes go with what directive.

**Which directive adds no prefix to the symbol?**

Comment: That's not possible.  You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  You are simply forgetting to link the DLL's import library.  Which tells the linker that _mylib_get_x is actually exported as mylib_get_x.  The import library, not the static library.

Comment: I solved my particular problem just now.  I was building an x64 lib and trying to import it into a x86 exe.  The linker errors makes no sense for this situation.  I think my question still stands, though as you say, it's not possible.